# ElasticBeanstalk system events and my application logs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS has a really nice log management tool. I can make my application log messages there very easy.

Amazon ElasticBeanstalk has a "event management" tool.

[image]

The questions are:

1. Can I log my app messages together in the ElasticBeanstalk events? Is it the syslog of the EC2 instance?
2. If yes, is this a good practice? Any problem on this? I was thinking about because, if there is no problem, I would not need any other third log management service.

Comment: This question should not be tagged with google-app-engine.

Answer (score 2):

The events shown in Elastic Beanstalk are internal to it. You are not supposed to fudge around with them (Although nobody is really preventing you from playing around with them).

Also, there's a log snapshot feature that picks up logs related to the application. These logs are mainly related to deployment and logging messages from the application itself. So, you can use this feature in case your application code is logging messages. For example, if you are running a Ruby/Rails with passenger you would get log messages under `/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log`. These are not syslog messages per se and the problem with this approach is that it's not straight forward the get your custom monitoring in place. For example, how do you parse your errors and send them to say [PagerDuty](https://www.pagerduty.com)?

Like you've probably figured out if you want to have custom monitoring (send logs to a syslog facility) you are better off using a third party tool like [Splunk Storm](https://www.splunkstorm.com/), [PaperTrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) or [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/). Of course you can setup your own syslog server(s) but that will require you to set up all the infrastructure.

Hope this helps.